# Sub-Directories Tracking In Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I would like to created a master view in Google Analytics that treats sub-directories page visits as one, not as two separate entries in the reports.

so instead of:

/us/brands
/gb/brands

Just shows total visits for /brands?

What is the best approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be probably to have an advanced filter that swaps the elements of your page path around - i.e. you turn /us/brands/ into "/brands/us". Then you can use a second filter to include only the "/brand" subdirectory into your view, and you get aggregated numbers.

A (perhaps better) alternative would be to create a [content grouping](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en) that includes your brand pages and then look at the pageviews/visit for that content grouping.